# Auto-Play feature not executing in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have somewhat of a baseball game, obviously there are not bases or hits. Its all stikes, balls and outs. The buttons work and the functionality of the inning (top and bottom as well as count) are working. I want this to ideally randomly throw a pitch on its own every few seconds. Basically to randomly "click" the ball or strike button. I am trying to use the setTimeout function with no success. Any help?

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bullpen.css"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Bullpen</title>
    </head>
</html>
    <body>

        <button id=buttons onclick="playBall()">Auto-Play</button>
        <h2>Inning: <span id=inningHalf></span> <span id=inningNum></span></h2>

    <div id=buttons>
        <button onclick="throwBall(), newInning()">Ball</button>
        <button onclick="throwStrike(), newInning()">Strike</button>
    </div>

        <h2>Count: <span id=ball>0</span> - <span id=strike>0</span></h2>
        <h2>Outs: <span id=out>0</span></h2>

        <h2>----------------</h2>

        <h2>Walks: <span id=walks>0</span></h2>
        <h2>Strikeouts: <span id=strikeout>0</span></h2>

        <script src="bullpen.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
  var ball = 0;
var strike = 0;
var out = 0;
var walks = 0;
var strikeout = 0;
//---------------------------------
var outPerInning = 0;
var inning = 1;
//---------------------------------
document.getElementById('inningNum').innerHTML = inning;
document.getElementById('inningHalf').innerHTML = '▲';

function throwBall(){
    ball++;
    document.getElementById('ball').innerHTML = ball;

    if (ball == 4){
    ball = 0;
    strike = 0;
    walks++;

    document.getElementById('walks').innerHTML = walks;
    document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('ball').innerHTML = 0;
    }
};

function throwStrike(){
    strike++;
    document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML = strike;

    if(strike == 3){
    ball = 0;
    strike = 0;
    strikeout++; 

    out++;
    outPerInning++;

    document.getElementById('strikeout').innerHTML = strikeout;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;
    document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('ball').innerHTML = 0;
    } 
};


function newInning(){
    if(out == 3){
    ball=0;
    strike=0;
    out=0;

    document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('ball').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = 0;
    }

    if(outPerInning == 3){
    document.getElementById('inningHalf').innerHTML = '▼';
    }

    if(outPerInning == 6){
        inning++;
    document.getElementById('inningHalf').innerHTML = '▲';
        outPerInning = 0;
    document.getElementById('inningNum').innerHTML = inning;
    } 
};

function playBall(){
    var play = Math.random;
    if(play >= 0.4){
        throwStrike();
        newInning();
    }
    else{
        throwBall();
        newInning();
    }

    setTimeout(playBall, 5000);
};
```

CSS if needed:

```
    h2{
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

button{
    font-size: 45px;
}

#buttons{
    width: 227px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is the problem:

```
function playBall(){
    var play = math.random;
    if(play >= 0.4){
        throwStrike;
        newInning();
    }
    else{
        throwBall;
        newInning();
    }

    setTimeout(playBall, 5000);
};
```

Should be

```
function playBall(){
    var play = Math.random();
    if(play >= 0.4){
        throwStrike(); //call the function
        newInning();
    }
    else{
        throwBall(); //call the function
        newInning();
    }

    setTimeout(playBall, 5000);
};
```

You were not calling these functions!

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/av6vsp7g/

Comment: thank you! I forgot to press the button after changing my code ha. Thanks a ton.